# Modal display <br> instant of next line

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

There is a while loop to display all data from database and there is a button on each div. When a user click the button then that particular information display in a modal. Actually its working fine but there is a small bug. Description added using "textarea" to the database. So it contains several paragraph which start in next line.
There is no next line when displaying the data in the modal. In the modal it display with "< br>" instant of next line. I want to display the text in a new line when a user click the modal. Please help me to fix it.

I've attached the error image. [image: Please check it]

```
<li>
   <div class="media wow fadeInDown articleclick" data-title="<?php echo $row2['title']; ?>" data-description="<?php echo nl2br($row2['article']); ?>" data-html="true" data-img="img/<?php if($row2['image']==''){ echo ''; } else { echo $row2['image']; } ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >
   <a href="#" class="media-left">
      <img alt="img" class="img-responsive" src="img/<?php if($row2['image']==''){ echo './noarticle.gif'; } else { echo $row2['image']; } ?>" style="height: 85%;">
   </a>
   <div class="media-body">
      <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="#"><?php echo $row2['title'];?></a></h4> 
   </div>
   </div>
</li>

<script>
 $(document).on("click", '.articleclick', function (e) {
   var description = $(this).data('description');
   var title = $(this).data('title');
   var img = $(this).data('img');
   $(".descrpdisplay").text(description);
   $(".titledisplay").text(title);
   $('.imgdisplay').attr('src', img);
 });
</script>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Articles</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img src="" class="img-responsive imgdisplay">
      <b><div class="titledisplay" style="padding: 25px 0px 10px 0px;"></div></b>
      <div class="descrpdisplay" ></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What problem do you try to resolve? When you parse your date to DB it is a problem to replace `\r\n` with something else. For example:

```
$text= $_POST["textarea"];
str_replace("\r\n"," ", $text);
```

When you try to show it on page - the same problem you can solve on PHP-side.

Otherwise you should prepare your text before send it to the back with JS or re-render before place it on you HTML.

```
str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '</p><p>');
```

In both case you know that any text should begin with `<p>` and end with `</p>`.And if there is line break as `\r\n` you should turn it to `</p><p>`.

Of course you will receive extra-paragraph on double line-breaks and should prevent it beforehand or after - on page display. Decide the "right side" and we'll expand solution for you.

UPD (some thoughts):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var textArea = $('textarea').text();
  console.log(textArea);

  $('.textBefore').text(textArea);
  
  var textAfter = ''
  + '<p>'
  +    textArea.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n|<br \/>|<br>)/g, '</p><p>')
  + '</p>';

  textAfter = textAfter.replace(/<p><\/p>/g, '');
  
  $('.textAfter').html(textAfter);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>
  Some 
  text 
  example
</textarea>
<div class="textBefore"></div>
<div class="textAfter"></div>
```

Comment: I want to display the next line in the frontend when a user click that particular div. I added the current error image. Can u help me to solve.

Comment: It didnt work @Daniel below code display in the modal <br /></p><p><br /></p><p>

Comment: Can you givean external link for the place it did not works? I've changed <br> to <br />pattern also. I've got a feeling that not only your code try to modify output.

Comment: Please click the article section on right from the above url.

Comment: oh, I see! You should change my `$('.textAfter').text(textAfter);` to `$('.textAfter').html(textAfter);` also. Do not forget to make replace changes we made before according to `<br />`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134298/discussion-between-daniel-and-user7152572).

Comment: it works now :) thanks u so much. I changed into .html(textAfter)

Comment: check empty `<p></p>` remover also

Comment: Early i use $(".descrpdisplay").text(description); now i use $(".descrpdisplay").html(description); its working fine. I think i dont want to use <p> </p>